# mysql select and several conditions, but meet the second if first one is not met

Tags: mysql

I have a situation with two tables here, first one is customers table and second one is policy tables. Policies can have several statuses - active, inactive, cancelled etc..

Now, I need to select customer and their active policies and cancelled policies ONLY if active does not exist!

It would be something like

```
SELECT c.customer_id, p.policy_id 
FROM table_customer as c
INNER JOIN table_policy as p ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id
WHERE p.status = 'active' OR p.status = 'cancelled' 
//(but select cancelled only if there are no active)
```

Is this possible to be done within one query?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if something does not exist, you can use [`not exists`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html), which checks if a (dependent) subquery is (not) empty:

```
SELECT c.customer_id, p.policy_id 
FROM table_customer as c
INNER JOIN table_policy as p ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id
WHERE p.status = 'active' 
   OR (p.status = 'cancelled' 
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_policy as p1 
                       WHERE p1.customer_id = p.customer_id 
                       AND p1.status = 'active'))
```

This can conveniently directly be read as *select customer and their active policies and cancelled policies ONLY if [an] active [policy for this customer] does not exist*.

Just maybe a note to the `1` in `select 1`: since it doesn't matter what you select, just that something is there, `1` is just a convenient choice.